# Using nohup to help run a loop of python code while disconnecting from ssh

Tags: linux, python-2.7, loops, ssh, nohup

I'm looking for help running a python script that takes some time to run.
It is a long running process that takes about 2hours per test observation.  For example, these observations could be the 50 states of the usa.

I dont want to baby sit this process all day - I'd like to kick it off then drive home from work - or have it run while I'm sleeping.

Since this a loop - I would need to call one python script that loops through my code going over each of the 50 states - and a 2nd that runs my actual code that does things.

I've heard of NOHUP, but I have very limited knowledge.   I saw nohup ipython mypython.py  but then when I google I get alot of other people chiming in with other methods and so I don't know what is the ideal approach for someone like me.  Additionally, I am essentially looking to run this as a loop - so don't know how that complicates things.

Please give me something simple and easier to understand.  I don't know linux all that well or I wouldn't be asking as this seems like a common sort of command/activity...

Basic example of my code:

### Two files:  code_file.py and loop_file.py

Code_file.py does all the work.  Loop file just passes in the list of things to run the stuff for.

#### code_file.py

```
output = each_state + ' needs some help!'
print output
```

#### loop_file.py

```
states = ['AL','CO','CA','NY','VA','TX']
for each_state in states:
    code_file.py
```

Regarding the loop - I have also heard that I can't pass in parameters or something via nohup?  I can fix this part within my python code....for example reading from a CSV in my code and deleting the current record from that CSV file and then re-writing it out...that way I can always select the top record in the CSV file for my loop (the list of states)

Answer (score -1):

May be you could modify your loop_file.py like this:

```
import os    
states = ['AL','CO','CA','NY','VA','TX']
    for each_state in states:
        os.system("python /dir_of_your_code/code_file.py")
```

Then in a shell, you could run the loop_file.py with:

`nohup python loop_file.py &`  # & is not necessary, it just redirect all output of the file to a file named nohup.out instead of printing it on screen.

Comment: Not all the print statements in `code_file.py` is printed to `nohup.out`